# MongoDB: Increase Index Key Limit in WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, indexing, wiredtiger

Where can I change index key limit with WiredTiger? Using mongodb version 3.0.4.

With version 2.6.7 we changed it at /db/structure/btree/btree.h from 1024 to 2048 and compiled the code to support larger index key.

Comment: Changing the source code in such a way is basically going to invalidate any chance of professional support in the future. You should also perhaps consider the settings on these things are there for a reason. Change at your own peril.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been pushed down to the [storage engine](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.0.4/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_index.cpp#L68) although there may be [other checks](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.0.4/src/mongo/db/index/external_key_generator.cpp#L190) elsewhere in the code that you could run into issues with.

At this point, if [SERVER-3372](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3372) makes it into the 3.2 release (**update:** now marked for 3.3 so did not make it to 3.2) this would become redundant, so I would just wait for that release and avoid having to update, support and compile your own version of MongoDB.

Comment: I see there is still limit on Index Key in 3.2. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit. Do I need to change the code at  other than https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.0.4/src/mongo/db/index/external_key_generator.cpp#L190 & https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.0.4/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_index.cpp#L68 ?

Comment: Yes, looks like this one has been pushed to 3.3, so it missed for 3.2 - I no longer work at MongoDB so I can't offer any insight into the decision at this point.